# how to write a regular expression that accept -90.000000 to 90.000000?

Tags: regex, range

I want a regular expression that validate input range -90.000000 to 90.000000.

I had `/^(\+|-)?(?:90((?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9])((?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$/`

But in the above expression when I enter .1 or 89. it fails. I want to ignore (`.`) dot. If I provide (`89.`) it should not fail. So please edit my expression so that if I put dot some digit or some digit dot it should not fail.

Comment: Why do you need to use regular expressions?

Comment: See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/MlWEz6/1).

Comment: You really should not use a regex to validate a range.  Use a regex at most to check that the input is a number, then simply use math to check that it is in a range.

Comment: Agree wholeheartedly with @dan1111 - this is not a job for regex.

Comment: His question is not "*how should I do this*", but "*which regex does this*"

Comment: @Gawil challenging the premise of the question is always fair game.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Yes I was trying this but I tried with math then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catch here is that you need to allow there to be no digits before a decimal point, *or* no digits after the decimal point.  But you don't want to allow just `.`.

There is no straightforward way to enforce that in a regex.  The best option is simply to add one of those options as a special case:

```
^[+-]?(?:90(?:\.0{0,6})?|(?:[1-8]?[0-9])(?:\.[0-9]{0,6})|(?:\.[0-9]{1,6}))$
```

This regex matches one of three distinct options:

- Number starting with 90, possibly with some zeros: `(?:90(?:\.0{0,6})?`
- Number less than 90, optionally with a decimal portion: `(?:[1-8]?[0-9])(?:\.[0-9]{0,6})`
- Number starting with a decimal point: `(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})`

That should fix your immediate problem.

However, **you really should not use a regex to validate a range.**

This is a confusing, counterintuitive way to implement a range check.  The fact that you need a quite complicated expression to perform a simple check kind of proves that point.

And this is a quite simple case.  Imagine if you needed to check that a number was between -89.325 and 125.5?  Suddenly the problem would explode in complexity.

This approach is harder to code, harder for someone else to understand, and harder to maintain in the future.  I would avoid it.

A better option would be a two step approach:

1. Check that the input is numeric (use a regex for this part if you don't have another good way of checking whether something is numeric).
2. Use simple comparisons to check whether the number is in range.

Comment: sure I will not check the range just asked the question.